# Property does not exist on type IntrinsicClassAttributes<Button>

Tags: react-native

I must admit these are  my first steps in ReactNative world.

I tried upgrade all npm libraries, and if I run build command I got a lot of errors, like:

`Property 'underlayColor' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Button> & Readonly<ButtonProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.`

`Property 'backgroundColor' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Button> & Readonly<ButtonProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.`

`Property 'textStyle' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Button> & Readonly<ButtonProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.`

etc.

and it's strange, because I did quick research and properties like above are available for  element. My question is: Is there a additional library or build element should I add? Or mayby the properties are really disabled for Button component in the newest version of react native?

**EDIT**
Example part of my code: Error is about missing underlayColor

```
<View style={[styles.modal.footer]}>
    <Button
     buttonStyle={styles.common.buttonTransparent}
     onPress={() => requestAnimationFrame(() => this.setState({isModalVisible: false}))}
     title={I18n.t('CANCEL')}
     underlayColor={styles.palette.transparent}
     textStyle={styles.modal.actionButtonText}
     containerViewStyle={styles.modal.actionButtonContainer}
    />
    <Button
     buttonStyle={styles.common.buttonTransparent}
     onPress={this.createReport}
     title={I18n.t('CREATE')}
     underlayColor={styles.palette.transparent}
     textStyle={styles.modal.actionButtonText}
     containerViewStyle={styles.modal.actionButtonContainer}
    />
</View>
```

Comment: Can you share the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Error suggests that `textStyle` and `underlayColor` are not valid props for your component `Button`. Seems like you imported button from some library. Check your library documentation carefully.

Also, check your style, it should be containing `backgroundColor` which is not valid.